# Android app dev - base project contains errors

Tags: android

I made a new project using Eclipse (API level 14, BlankActivity, Tabs+Swipe.)

The entire `src` folder contains `@Override` errors which I can fix. 
However, the `AndroidManifest.xml` file shows an error:

```
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

How do I fix this?

Here is the unchanged, default xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sohamchowdhury.ferric"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sohamchowdhury.ferric"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AspectListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_aspect_list" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AspectDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_aspect_detail" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".AspectListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sohamchowdhury.ferric"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you have too many `manifests`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one manifest tags inside your xml file.
Remove the following part from your code.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sohamchowdhury.ferric"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And make sure you have xml declaration present on very first line of your manifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: I dont know the exact reason behind it. This problem wasn't there upto API 13 . I guess sometimes eclipse couldn't resolve and load the newly created projects properly.

Comment: Accept the answer if it has solved your problem. It increases reputation of both the parties.